# How do I hook up a Bootstrap dropdown to an eventhandler using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Since a Bootstrap dropdown is actually a ul, I am confused on how to actually "hook it up" to functionality via jQuery.

For example, on the click of a submit button, I want something different to happen depending on which drop-down item is currently selected. See drop down code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button id='businessType' class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Business Type
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Brewery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to do something like this:

```
var chosenType = $('businessType').val();
```

to get either Bar, Brewery, or Food and then use that chosenType variable to do something in my application but it's not working that way. I cannot seem to find this in the docs or any previous question which addresses this.

Answer (score 1):

Need to use jQuery selector
for single selection :

```
$($('#businessType').parent().find('ul.dropdown-menu li a')[0]).text()
```

for all selection :

```
   $.each($('#businessType').parent().find('ul.dropdown-menu li a'),function(i,v){ console.log($(v).text());
    })
```

Comment: @Tee See.If this solves your purpose. Please accept the answer.

Comment: unfortunately, this only selects the text from the list item, I'm talking about a selector which **determines which list item is actually selected by the user.** `$($('#businessType').parent().find('ul.dropdown-menu li a')[0]).text()` selects the first dropdown item _regardless_ of what is selected by the user.

The only way to do this that I've found so far is `<li><a href="#" onclick="setVariables('Bars')">Bar</a></li>` however, is there a more effective way?